# Как перевести код из java в jquery

Tags: javascript

Плохо разбираюсь в javaScript. Так уж сложилось, что начал сразу с jQuery. На сайте нашел код, который в Java и не могу перевести его в привычный мне Jquery.

```
const signInBtn = document.getElementById("signIn");
const signUpBtn = document.getElementById("signUp");
const fistForm = document.getElementById("form1");
const secondForm = document.getElementById("form2");
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

signInBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    container.classList.remove("right-panel-active");
});

signUpBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    container.classList.add("right-panel-active");
});

fistForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => e.preventDefault());
secondForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => e.preventDefault());
```

Comment: Java и JavaScript - это разные ЯП.

Comment: "Кто-нибудь может помочь? " --- конечно могут. на фрилансе много людей желающих помочь

Comment: В jquery элементы ищутся через css-селекторы. Метод querySelector работает через css-селекторы, поэтому хватит перенести как есть. Метод getElementById ищет по атрибуту id, у css-селекторов для этого используется выражение с `#`, например `#signIn`. Для addEventListener ищите соответствующие методы, типа https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 1):

### Как перевести JavaScript в JQuery

1. Изучить синтаксис\основы JavaScript

> Например [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/)

2. Так же подтянуть JQuery

> Например [тут](https://api.jquery.com/)

3. И вы у цели!